# Dynamically add a row to a SQL results set

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

i have written a SP to retrieve a results set. So the following SQL section would give me the results set as i wanted:

```
SELECT *
FROM `temp_table` JOIN `mytable` ON `mytable_ID` = `temp_table_tmp_id`
WHERE CEILING(`tmp_idx`/int_page_size) = p_page_no
```

Now, i need to add a dynamic row to the above results set, thus, i have tried the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM `temp_table` JOIN `mytable` ON `mytable_ID` = `temp_table_tmp_id`
WHERE CEILING(`tmp_idx`/int_page_size) = p_page_no
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT `ID`, `temp_table_tmp_id`,`Name`, 100, `Type`,`Description`
ORDER BY `tmp_idx`;
```

But this gives "Unknown column 'tmp_idx' in 'field list'" error for each of those fields i have defined in SELECT statement after "UNION ALL". I have put "100" as a value which should be indicated in the results set. I hope this is clear enough with what i want to achieve. Please let me know how this can be corrected/achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using MySQL to achieve this.

Comment: Try using apostrophe (ie ') instead of back-tick (`) to delimit your column headers in the dynamic row. Also, you will have to convert all numeric columns to formatted strings in your base query.

Comment: what is tmp_ind? is this field of the first union select?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Awesome. Works like a charm. BTW how do i add this record as the last record of my results set? 

Because i tried SELECT DISTINCT 'tmp_idx','','','','','','','','' and it added as 'tmp_idx' as the unique ID. i want to add as the next increment number in the results set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using apostrophe (ie ') instead of back-tick (`) to delimit your column headers in the dynamic row. Also, you will have to convert all numeric columns to formatted strings in your base query.

To control the sequencing, so that the artificial row is forced to appear last, add another column `sequence` with a hard-coded value of 0 for the data rows, and of 1 for the dynamic row. Then add this new column `sequence` at the front of the ORDER BY. (In some SQL dialects it is necessary either to identify this column by ordinal number instead of by name, or to add a wrapper query that contains the order by clause.)

Comment: I solved by getting a count of the total results + 1 as the next number :) Thanks a lot for the help @PieterGeerkens

Comment: That works too. The best thanks is always a vote, of course. ;-)